# Exception is not thrown when using Mockito's doThrow method

Tags: java, spring, testing, junit, mockito

I am working with a mocked object like the following:

```
@Mock
private RecipeService recipeService
```

I also have the following method inside the test class:

```
    @Test
    public void testAddRecipeWithNonUniqueName() throws Exception {
        Recipe recipe = new Recipe();

        doThrow(Exception.class)
                .when(recipeService)
                .save(recipe);

        mockMvc.perform(post("/recipes/add-recipe")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
                .param("id", "1")
                .param("name", "recipe1"))
                .andExpect(status().is3xxRedirection())
                .andExpect(view().name("redirect:/recipes/add"));
    }
```

As you can see, I am using mockito's `doThrow` method to decide what exception is going to be thrown when the `void` method named `save` is called.

I want to make a POST request using a `MockMvc` object. So the method marked with the `/recipes/add-recipe` endpoint will be called inside one of my controller classes. The following snippet of code shows that method in detail:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/recipes/add-recipe", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addRecipe(@Valid Recipe recipe, BindingResult result, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes,
                            @AuthenticationPrincipal User user){

       String response = validateFormValues(recipe, redirectAttributes, result,
               "redirect:/recipes/add");
       if(!response.isEmpty())return response;

        recipe.setUser(user);

        try {
            recipeService.save(recipe);
        }catch(Exception e){
            redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("uniqueConstraintError",
                    String.format("The name \"%s\" is already taken by another recipe. " +
                                    "Please try again!",
                            recipe.getName()));
            return "redirect:/recipes/add";
        }

        setUserForIngredientsAndSteps(recipe);

        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("flash",
                new FlashMessage("The recipe has been added successfully!", FlashMessage.Status.SUCCESS));
        return String.format("redirect:/recipes/%s/detail", recipe.getId());
    }
```

The above method contains a **try-catch** block. When the `recipeService.save()` is called, I am expecting that an exception will be thrown, and handled by the catch block. **But that doesn't happen.** **Instead, the other lines are executed.**

**What am I missing ?**

Comment: Where are you actually passing in the mock?

Comment: You are throwing an exception only when the exact same instance of `Recipe` is being called. Instead use `any()` as the matcher.

Comment: @M.Deinum Now I see. Simple mistake from my part. But now I would have a different problem. The `save` method can take in this case either a `Recipe` or a `List<Recipe>` object. So if I call `any()`, I would get the "Ambiguous method call" compilation error. What should I do in this case ?

Comment: Use `any(Recipe.class)`.

Comment: @M.Deinum It works now. Thank you.

Comment: As a side note, you should almost never `catch Exception`, and certainly not here; there are any number of other error conditions besides duplicates that you shouldn't treat all alike.

Comment: @chrylis I totally agree. That is just a code smell that I consider acceptable for now. Thank you for your note.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Recipe recipe = new Recipe();

doThrow(Exception.class)
        .when(recipeService)
        .save(recipe);
```

This code will only work if the exact same instance of `Recipe` is passed to the save method. If you have implemented an `equals` and/or `hashCode` method passing in a `Recipe` instance if the expected values `1` and `name` might make it work.

```
Recipe recipe = new Recipe();
recipe.setId(1);
recipe.setName("name");

doThrow(Exception.class)
        .when(recipeService)
        .save(recipe);
```

However as you probably want to test the error situation it is probably easier to always throw an exception. For this use the [`any()`](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.24.0/org/mockito/ArgumentMatchers.html#any-java.lang.Class-) matcher.

```
doThrow(Exception.class)
        .when(recipeService)
        .save(any(Recipe.class);
```

Now upon calling save, regardless of the passed in `Recipe` the exception will be thrown.

Answer (score 2):

the `doTrhow()` method you are calling is triggered only when you save on the specific recipe you created before.

You need to tell Mockito to throw on any recipe

```
Mockito.doThrow(Exception.class)
            .when(recipeService)
            .save(Mockito.any(Recipe.class));
```